# Can I do a constraint check in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, constraints

I want to use a stored procedure to check if a status is inserted. I know that I can just have the constraint from the designing the table, I just want to do it in a procedure.

```
create procedure Service_Status(@service_status varchar(15))
AS
  Begin
     IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ServiceStatus WHERE   
      [status]=@service_status))
     --Check ([status] in ('Pending','In-Progress','Closed'))
       BEGIN
       SELECT 'Status must be either Pending, In-Progress or Closed'
       END

END
```

Comment: Why? Just use a check constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on procedure then I don't think you can - how are you planning to bind that stored procedure to the insert & update events?

You can encapsulate your check code in a user defined function, but then you need to call that functions in a constraint (you seem not to aim that), you can also create a trigger (probably not advisable), but I really don't see how will you enforce a stored procedure check on an insert / update event.